# How does this not cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c#

I'm looking at the source code for a server using SocketAsyncEventArgs, and I'm trying to figure out how this wouldn't cause a stack overflow:

So this code is called to allow the socket to accept an incoming connection (scroll down to the bottom to see what I mean):

```
/// <summary>
/// Begins an operation to accept a connection request from the client.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="acceptEventArg">The context object to use when issuing 
/// the accept operation on the server's listening socket.</param>
private void StartAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg)
{
    if (acceptEventArg == null)
    {
        acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnAcceptCompleted);
    }
    else
    {
        // Socket must be cleared since the context object is being reused.
        acceptEventArg.AcceptSocket = null;
    }

    this.semaphoreAcceptedClients.WaitOne();
    Boolean willRaiseEvent = this.listenSocket.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
    if (!willRaiseEvent)
    {
        this.ProcessAccept(acceptEventArg);
    }
}
```

Then this code gets called once a connection is actually accepted (see last line):

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Process the accept for the socket listener.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">SocketAsyncEventArg associated with the completed accept operation.</param>
        private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref this.numConnectedSockets);
                Console.WriteLine("Client connection accepted. There are {0} clients connected to the server",
                    this.numConnectedSockets);
            }

            // Get the socket for the accepted client connection and put it into the 
            // ReadEventArg object user token.
            SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = this.readWritePool.Pop();
            readEventArgs.UserToken = e.AcceptSocket;

            // As soon as the client is connected, post a receive to the connection.
            Boolean willRaiseEvent = e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
                this.ProcessReceive(readEventArgs);
            }

            // Accept the next connection request.
            this.StartAccept(e); // <==== tail end recursive?
        }
```

Look at the last line. It calls the top function again. How does this not overflow the stack by ping-ponging back and forth between these 2 functions? It seems to be tail end recursion, but this isn't Haskell so I don't see how this would work.

It was my understanding that these weren't fired in threads but where just executed one at a time by the cpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the AsyncAccept (or any AsyncXXX operation for that matter) cannot be satisfied immediately, then it will return true, indicating that the operation will complete asynchronously. When this happens, the callback-event will ultimately fire on a thread-pool thread. Even if it marshal's back to a UI thread (because it was initiated there), it will do so via a post.

AsyncAccept is *highly* likely to return true, because unless there are socket connections truly pending (see backlog in [Listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen.aspx)), you are waiting for a client to connect.

Hence, StartAccept() will simply exit without calling ProcessAccept, and ProcessAccept when (and if) it fires, will probably be on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code:

```
if (!willRaiseEvent)
{
    this.ProcessAccept(acceptEventArg);
}
```

Although I don't yet understand the whole mechanism, willRaiseEvent == true will clearly end the recursion, so I guess this happens so it's not endless recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the `willCauseEvent` flag, that when set to true breaks the recursion.
That flag is probably set to true in case there's no connection pending.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to determine from the context, but looks like the first only calls the second directly when

```
Boolean willRaiseEvent = this.listenSocket.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);    
if (!willRaiseEvent)    
{
```

and thus I'm guessing most of the time it raises an event on completion (from a different callback thread)?

(See also the 'stack dive' portion of

http://blogs.msdn.com/mjm/archive/2005/05/04/414793.aspx

which seems to be a similar kind of thing.)

Answer (score 0):

`ProcessAccept()` **always** calls `StartAccept()` but the reverse is not true.

In `StartAccept()`, `ProcessAccept()` is only called if `willRaiseEvent` is set to true. That's your exit from the infinite recursion right there.

You always look for the possible exit points if you suspect infinite recursion (in either a single recursive function or one of your ping-pong ones, as you so eloquently put it :-).